# Error Log fromHost re Magento Install How do i Fix them

Tags: log, http-status-403

I am getting a few errors in my Host Log from my Magento install.

Getting a lot of these

1. [141.101.99.184:48065] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml]
2. [141.101.99.184:9599] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml]
3. [141.101.99.160:47913-3#APVH_anditsgone.co.uk] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml] 
   2016-02-23 22:36:17.255
4. [141.101.99.160:47913-2#APVH_anditsgone.co.uk] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml]
5. [141.101.99.160:30798-2#APVH_anditsgone.co.uk] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml]
6. [141.101.99.160:47913-1#APVH_anditsgone.co.uk] File not found [/home/freetime/public_html/403.shtml]

They all seem related to the 403 error any ideas please.

Thorrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you either have a custom module that points 403 HTTP errors to this file or maybe a webserver configuration like described here: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/02/13/davidsklar.html

This directive could also be in your .htaccess file

Comment: Hello, David thank you for your quick reply. Please could you break it down a little i am not an expert and would appreciate a little more guidance on what to check  if you do not mind

Thorrrr

Comment: first step I would recommend is to search the .htaccess file in your magento root dir for "ErrorDocument 403". If you do not find anything, you should ask your hosting provider if they configured any error document directives in your virtual host.

Comment: Is this root to the whole host site or in the public_html root for Magento. As you know there are several htacess files

Comment: this should be in the public_html directory in your case

Comment: I found nothing i have sent a query to host providers.

Comment: HI Reply from Host Providers "These 403 errors don’t seem to be something you should be concerned about. When you pull up your website, if at all some resources mentioned on it don’t load or is not available at the time, the logs would have a 403 entry for it. As long as your website loads without issues, you can ignore these notifications that show up in your error log" I would still like to get rid of them is possible

Comment: if your hoster refuses to provide a default 403 page, you might just configure it to point to magentos 404 page or you add an own 403 page. In your .htaccess file you could add something like ErrorDocument 403 errors/404.php